# Flot library setting up y axis to min 0 and max 24

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

How can i set up my y axis to be in the range of 0 to 24

Here is the code i have.

```
  j$.plot(j$("#placeholder"),[d1],{
        xaxis: 
        { mode: "time", 
            min: (new Date("2010/11/01")).getTime(),
            max: (new Date("2011/02/01")).getTime()
            }
 },
  {yaxis: { min:0, max:24 } };
  };
```

xaxis seemed to work but when i added y axis it doesnt work.

Apart from this 
d1 holds the string which is sent from salesforce

for example  d1 holds

```
[1294041600000,14.00],[1294041600000,14.50],[1294041600000,15.00],[1293955200000,12.00]
```

I am not able to view the graph,  currently i am having the y axis showing only the range -1 to 1, i am assuming this could be the reason why i am not seeing the line.

thanks

Prady

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The y axis problem was solved. Here is the code

```
j$.plot(j$("#placeholder"), [d1], {
    xaxis: 
    {
      mode: "time", 
      min: (new Date("2010/11/01")).getTime(),
      max: (new Date("2011/02/01")).getTime()
    },

    yaxis:
    {
        min:0, max: 24,  tickSize: 5 
    }
});
```

Comment: @andig I don't think so, looks like there was an extra set of curly braces around `yaxis: ...` that was messing everything up.