# Flot linegraph whitespace

Tags: whitespace, flot, linegraph

I made a linegraph in flot, which looks very nice, but i would like a slight change.

I would like a little whitespace before the line starts, and a little whitespace when the graph ends. The horizontal gridlines need to start already, so that the graph just looks more spacious.

Thanks for your anwsers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an explicit xaxis/yaxis min and max, as described in the [Customizing the Axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) section of the docs.

Another possibility, for vertical space, is to use autoscaleMargin, as described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095387/jquery-flot-more-space-at-the-top).